# Show that $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ if and only if $x\in A_k$ for infinitely many sets $A_k$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ then $x\in \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ and $x\in \bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty}A_k$ and so on so that $x\in \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$, but since $x\in \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\space \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ $\implies x\in \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k \implies\space x\in A_k$ for infinitely many sets $A_k$.

Conversely, Let $x\in A_k$ for infinitely many sets $A_k$. Let $x\in A_1\implies x\in\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$. Now, suppose $x\notin A_1$ but $x\in A_2\implies x\in\bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty}A_k$. Continue in this manner, so that $x\notin A_k, \forall k\in\{1,...,n-1\}$ but $x\in A_n$ and $x\in\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k $. Now, $\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\subseteq...\subseteq  \bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty}A_k\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$. So, $x\in \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\implies x\in \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\implies x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Is this a proof-verification? If so, you should tag it thus

Comment: In second line in last implication the premise is not enough for conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use more words and fewer formulae:

Suppose $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$.

We want to show that $x$ is in $A_k$ for infinitely many $k$ so we assume $x \in A_k$ *only* for $A_k$ among $A_{n_1}, A_{n_2}, \ldots, A_{n_m}$, $m$ many sets.
Now if $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ is picked to be larger than all indices $\{n_1, \ldots, n_m\}$ we know that $x \notin \bigcup_{k=n_0}^\infty A_k$ as no set with index $\ge n$ can contain $A_k$ by assumption, so this $n_0$ contradict $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$, so our assumption that $x$ is in only finitely many $A_k$ was false. This shows one inclusion.

To show the reverse, assume that for some $x$ the set $N_x=\{k\mid x \in A_k\}$ is infinite. To see that $x \in  \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$, let $n \in \Bbb N$ be arbitrary. Then $N_x$ contains some $k \ge  n$ or $N_k$ would have been finite (atmost size $n$ in fact). So we have some $k$ (depending on $n$) such that $k \ge n$ and $x \in A_k$. This shows that $x \in \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ for this $n$ and as $n$ was arbitrary, $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

By definition,
$$x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \Longleftrightarrow \forall n \geq 1, \exists k \geq n \text{ s.t. } x \in A_k $$

So you deduce
$$x \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \Longleftrightarrow \exists n \geq 1, \forall k \geq n \text{ s.t. } x \notin A_k $$ $$\Longleftrightarrow x \text{ is in a finite number of } A_k$$